# Generalization of std::transform

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11

Consider this simple generalization of std::transform I wrote for N input iterators:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

template <typename InputIterator, typename OutputIterator, typename NaryOperator, typename... InputIterators>
OutputIterator transform (InputIterator first, InputIterator last, OutputIterator result,
NaryOperator op, InputIterators... iterators) {
    while (first != last) {
        *result = op(*first, *iterators++...);
        ++result;  ++first;
    }
    return result;
}

int main() {
    const std::vector<int> a = {1,2,3,4,5};
    const std::vector<double> b = {1.2, 4.5, 0.6, 2.8, 3.1};
    const std::vector<std::string> c = {"hi", "howdy", "hello", "bye", "farewell"};
    std::vector<double> result(5);
    transform (a.begin(), a.end(), result.begin(),
        [](int i, double d, const std::string& s)->double {return i + d + s.length();},
        b.begin(), c.begin());
    for (double x : result) std::cout << x << ' ';  // 4.2 11.5 8.6 9.8 16.1
}
```

What I want to do now, is allow the vectors `a`, `b`, `c` to have different lengths (and the argument `InputIterator last` can be removed), in which case `transform` will continue transforming until the longest vector is used up, using the default values for the vectors that are shorter.

I thought this would just be a matter of resizing all the short containers within the `transform` function, but the arguments of `transform` give no information about how long all the containers are.  Is there a way to compute within `transform` how long each of the containers are, thereby getting the maximum length and thus filling the default values for the shorter containers?  Ideally using just the syntax:

```
transform (OutputIterator result, NaryOperator op, InputIterators... iterators);
```

**Update:**  Following Ramana's idea, I am thinking of using something like:

```
template <typename OutputIterator, typename NaryOperator, typename... InputIterators>
OutputIterator transform (OutputIterator result, NaryOperator op, InputIterators... first, InputIterators... last) {
    while (true) {
        *result = op((first == last ?
            typename std::iterator_traits<InputIterators>::value_type() : *first++)...);
        ++result;
    }
    return result;
}
```

But

```
transform (result.begin(),
    [](int i, double d, const std::string& s)->double {return i + d + s.length();},
    a.begin(), b.begin(), c.begin(), a.end(), b.end(), c.end());
```

does not compile. I think because the compiler does not know where `last...` begins.

So I tried this next:

```
template <typename OutputIterator, typename NaryOperator, typename... InputIteratorsPairs>
OutputIterator transform (OutputIterator result, NaryOperator op, InputIteratorsPairs... pairs) {
    while (true) {
        *result = op((pairs.first == pairs.second ?
            typename InputIteratorsPairs::first_type() : *pairs.first++)...);
        ++result;
    }
    return result;
}
```

But

```
transform_ (result.begin(),
    [](int i, double d, const std::string& s)->double {return i + d + s.length();},
    std::make_pair(a.begin(), a.end()), std::make_pair(b.begin(), b.end()), std::make_pair(c.begin(), c.end()));
```

does not compile either (and I don't like the syntax anyway).

Comment: [`std::distance()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance)?

Comment: How about redefining iterators++ to stop advancing when it is at the end and return the default value for the container?

Comment: @ The Paramagnetic Croissant  You mean call `iterators++..` until any of them reaches "the end", and then compute length using std::distance?  How to know when "the end" is reached?

Comment: @prestokeys No. You call `std::distance()` on each begin-end pair of iterators, which will return the size of the respective vector. Then you take the maximum of those sizes.

Comment: @prestokeys BTW, you could do it as you described (but it's not worth the pain). You reached the end when the last iterator you've got reaches its end position.

Comment: So you mean `InputIterators... iterators` must be `first1, last1, first2, last2, ...` instead of just `first1, first2, first3, ....` which I was originally thinking?  The second way would be fruitless?

Comment: Out of curiosity, which is a real use case you have in mind?

Comment: No use case (yet).  Just a challenge exercise I came up with after carrying out the above original exercise.  @ Ramana  I can't think of how to reformulate `iterators++...` to check if any of them has reached the end.  How to use an if statement on a pack?  Use the comma operator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>
#include <iterator>

bool all(bool a)
{
    return a;
}

template <typename... B>
bool all(bool a, B... b)
{
    return a && all(b...);
}

template <typename OutputIterator, typename NaryOperator, typename... InputIterators, std::size_t... Is>
OutputIterator transform(OutputIterator result, NaryOperator op, std::index_sequence<Is...>, InputIterators... iterators)
{
    auto tuple = std::make_tuple(iterators...);
    while (!all(std::get<2*Is>(tuple) == std::get<2*Is + 1>(tuple)...))
    {
        *result = op((std::get<2*Is>(tuple) != std::get<2*Is + 1>(tuple)
              ? *std::get<2*Is>(tuple)++
              : typename std::iterator_traits<typename std::tuple_element<2*Is, decltype(tuple)>::type>::value_type{})...);
        ++result;
    }
    return result;
}

template <typename OutputIterator, typename NaryOperator, typename... InputIterators>
OutputIterator transform(OutputIterator result, NaryOperator op, InputIterators... iterators)
{
    return transform(result, op, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(InputIterators)/2>{}, iterators...);
}
```

*Tests:*

```
int main()
{
    const std::vector<int> a = {1,2,3,4,5};
    const std::vector<double> b = {1.2, 4.5, 0.6, 2.8, 3.1};
    const std::vector<std::string> c = {"hi", "howdy", "hello", "bye", "farewell"};
    std::vector<double> result(5);

    transform(result.begin(),
        [] (int i, double d, const std::string& s) -> double
        {
            return i + d + s.length();
        },
        a.begin(), a.end(),
        b.begin(), b.end(),
        c.begin(), c.end());

    for (double x : result) std::cout << x << ' ';
}
```

*Output:*

```
4.2 11.5 8.6 9.8 16.1
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/44f16fe9fcb6d08e)

Comment: with C++1z fold-expressions the `while` statement could be replaced by `while (((std::get<2*Is>(tuple) != std::get<2*Is + 1>(tuple)) || ...))`

Comment: If you are going to go this far, why not make them range-based?

Comment: [Like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31477580/1774667).  Gets rid of the need for an index sequence, but does still require the `using discard=int[];` expansion pack trick.

Answer (score 2):

```
pairs.first == pairs.second ?
        typename InputIteratorsPairs::first_type() : *pairs.first++
```

You are value-initializing an iterator on the left side of `:` instead of the type the iterator points to. Also you have an infinite loop and undefined behavior because you keep incrementing `result`. Here's a version that fixes these issues (requires `<algorithm>` and is not necessarily most efficient:

```
bool any(std::initializer_list<bool> vs)
{
    return std::any_of(begin(vs), end(vs), [](bool b) { return b; });
}

template<typename OutputIterator, typename NaryOperator, typename... InputIteratorsPairs>
OutputIterator transform(OutputIterator result, NaryOperator op, InputIteratorsPairs... pairs) {
    while (any({(pairs.first != pairs.second)...})) {
        *result = op((pairs.first == pairs.second ?
            typename InputIteratorsPairs::first_type::value_type() : *pairs.first++)...);
        ++result;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a range based solution.  Instead of operating on iterators, we operate on ranges of iterators.

A range is a pair of iterators with some helpers.  This is a minimal implementation with only some helpers written:

```
template<class It> using it_value_type =
  typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type;
template<class It> using it_reference =
  typename std::iterator_traits<It>::reference;

template<class It>
struct range_t {
  It b, e;
  range_t():b(),e(){}
  range_t(It s, It f):b(s),e(f){}
  template<class C, class=std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<std::decay_t<C>,range_t>{}>>
  range_t(C&& c):
    range_t(std::begin(c),std::end(c))
  {}
  It begin() const { return b; }
  It end() const { return e; }

  bool empty() const { return begin()==end(); }
  it_reference<It> front() const { return *begin(); }
  it_reference<It> back() const { return *std::prev(end()); }

  range_t pop_front() const {
    if (empty()) return {};
    else return {std::next(begin()), end()};
  }
};
```

A function to make creating `range_t`s easier:

```
template<class C, class It=std::decay_t<decltype(std::begin(std::declval<C&>()))>>
range_t<It> range( C&& c ) {
  return {std::begin(c), std::end(c)};
}
```

A helper to make checking a bunch of `bool`s to see if they are all true easier:

```
bool all_of( std::initializer_list<bool> il ) {
  return std::all_of( il.begin(), il.end(), [](bool b){return b;} );
}
```

Now for the work.  The range-based implementation of transform first:

```
template<class Sink, class Operator, class...Its>
Sink transform( Sink sink, Operator op, range_t<Its>... srcs ) {
  while(!all_of({srcs.empty()...})) {
    *sink++ = op( (srcs.empty()?it_value_type<Its>{}:srcs.front())... );
    using discard=int[];
    (void)discard{0,
      ((srcs = srcs.pop_front()),0)...
    };
  }
  return sink;
}
```

And the non-range-based implementation, which just forwards to the above:

```
template<class Sink, class Operator, class...Srcs>
Sink transform( Sink sink, Operator op, Srcs&&... srcs ) {
  return transform( sink, op, range(srcs)... );
}
```

they should be able to exist as overloads of each other.

Switching this to stop when the first range ends is easy -- swap `all_of` for `any_of`.

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/190fac37d8f3433f).